# Terminal Server Print Spooler Event Errors

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, terminal-server

We are running Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 with Terminal Services. We get the following error:

> Error 4/11/2012 3:35:30 PM    PrintService    808 Initializing
>
> ```
> Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Admin
> Source:        Microsoft-Windows-PrintService
> Date:          4/11/2012 3:35:30 PM
> Event ID:      808
> Task Category: Initializing
> Level:         Error
> Keywords:      Print Spooler
> User:          *************
> Computer:      *************
> Description:
> The print spooler failed to load a plug-in module C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\x64\3\UNIDRVUI.DLL, error code 0xc1.
> ```
>
> See the event user data for context information.

These errors only occur with computers that have windows 7 on them, XP computers do not throw any event error on the terminal server. HP Univeral Driver casuing this error? Or could it be Windows 7? RDP? There are 8 computers with Windows 7 and they usually have around 80 event errors per day between them all. **(EDIT: 1 XP)**

Comment: Did the computers start as Win7, or have they been upgraded from Vista?

Comment: These are all brand new out of the box Win7 Pro machines over the last couple months. A couple different manufacturers (HP & Dell...all desktop except for one laptop). The errors have been there for a bit, except when we added 2 new ones last week, I noticed today that all were new Win7. It can't be a coincidence. 50+ XP computers fine but not one win7 computer.

Comment: Any chance they're 64-bit devices with 32-bit drivers?

Comment: I was going over things again, thinking the same. I made a mistake and there is ONE XP machine giving this error. They are using one model of printer though. But I think I have to really go over the each individual machine and make sure (model/OS/drivers).